# Java ArrayList<String[]>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I would like to create a 2D array named `employees` where I know the number of columns (fixed 5 and represent employee's data) but number of rows is somewhat dynamic. So I did something like this:

```
static ArrayList<String[]> employees = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

I figured how to add employees but I can't figure out how to get a specific data out of one employee only, using `.get()` for example.

Comment: `employees.get(row)[column]` should work. eG ``employees.get(0)[1]``

Comment: Though it's probably easier to create a class `Employee` rather than use a `String[]`.

Answer (score 5):

`get` would return a row, which is a `String[]`. If you want a specific value from it, you'll have to subscript it using the `[]` operator:

```java
String specificData = employees.get(1)[2]; // Or any other indexes
```

Answer (score 2):

the first dimension which is any `ArrayList` you have to call by `get()` method to access and then the returned value is an array which you cann access by `index`:

```
ArrayList<String[]> employees = new ArrayList<String[]>();
employees.add(new String[] {"a", "b"});
System.out.println(employees.get(0)[0]);
```